# Zend_framework - relative paths of images

Tags: php, zend-framework, relative-path

When i am developing a web application on Zend_framework (php) i have to include images (css files, js files, etc).

The solution for inclusion was to specify the absolute paths each time i needed an image (i was storing in "global like" parameter with my host and concatenated it with the relative path of the image on the host). As i understand this solution is overpriced (for each picture to go the DNS service and so on) and i am looking for a simpler solution to the relative path problem.

P.S. The problem can be better described in the following example: when I am going to "http://myhost.com/" the images will be shown normally (the image path was: "./images/logo.jpg"). but it won't be seen from the "http://myhost.com/users/" url (to make it seen i had to change to image path to : "./../images/logo.jpg".

Id anybody knows how i can solve this problem, i will be glad to hear.

Gorelik.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for the [BaseUrl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.baseurl) helper.

```
<?php echo $this->baseUrl('images/logo.jpg'); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using site-root-relative paths instead of relative paths.

Simply remove that dot in your image path: `./images/logo.jpg` should be `/images/logo.jpg`. The leading dot makes it a path relative to the current URL (so it needs to be changes depending on where you are on the site). Without a dot it's a path relative to the root, so it works everywhere without any need to change it.

Also have a look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181805/absolute-path-relative-path) and the links in its answers.

Comment: I second this solution because it does not add the overhead of invoking the baseUrl helper.

Comment: What happens if his website is in a subdirectory? `http://myhost.com/blah/blah/public/` => `http://myhost.com/images/logo.jpg`

Comment: Using a helper is the most flexible solution since he can move his site without worrying about breaking paths. The `baseUrl` helper queries the Front Controller for the current base URL. You could also write your own base URL helper using config values. *Premature optimisation blah blah :)*

Comment: Fair call, a `base` element will also do it :)

Answer (score 1):

> As i understand this solution is
>   overpriced (for each picture to go the
>   DNS service and so on) and i am
>   looking for a simpler solution to the
>   relative path problem.

I don't believe that is true.

Even if you were using full absolute URLs, including the hostname, you wouldn't incur a DNS lookup on every image.  Rest assured that the client OS (and in some cases, I think, the browser) is caching that stuff for you.

Of course, there's no reason to use full-qualified URLs.  Just go absolute from the server root:

```
<?PHP
// somewhere in config.php or similar:
define('SITE_ROOT_URL_PATH','/myapplication');
...
// meanwhile, in some template
<img src="<?php echo SITE_ROOT_URL_PATH . '/images/foo.jpg'; ?>" />
```

If your app is running in the web root, just set DITE_ROOT_URL_PATH to ''

You could even create a little helper function to save you some keystrokes: imgurl('foo.jpg').

I've used this method for years, and never had any headaches.  Unless I'm missing something in the question, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

Code:

```
$imgurl=$this->layout()->staticBaseUrl.'application/themes/themes-files/images/filename.jpg';
```

Html:

```
<img src="<?php echo $imgurl; ?> " width="50" height="50"/>
```

:)