# Site dependencies and CSS not loading

Tags: html, css

I am trying to publish [my site](http://pearsoncreamery.com) (it's a modified html template) to my server.

I can't get the site to load the dependencies, it only shows the text.

I tried changing each `href` to the appropriate file, where the host says it searches for the index.html. I have tried to change all the local `file://` `href`s to corresponding root site values, as the source shows. Why isn't this working?

I was surprised that DW6 doesn't just change the coding when putting a managed site. Shouldn't it load the CSS? I do have all the files and folders on the remote site.

for example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public_html/css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

yet it appears as this: www.pearsoncreamery.com

Answer (score 2):

Your site is looking for url's like: "http://pearsoncreamery.com/public_html/css/reset.css".

"public html" is the root of your site, so you should omit that after the slash - ie. it should just be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

or if the page making the call is not in the site's root you need the slash:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. thanks ethan. Up and running thanks to you!

Comment: Glad to help. Remember to tick this answer as accepted if you're done :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the path from the web root to the file. Your current code refers to the absolute path in the file system. You probably need

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

Answer (score 0):

- Understand the [difference between absolute and relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181805/absolute-path-relative-path).
- When you include `/public_html/` in your `<link>` and `<scripts>` elements, you are in fact requestin `http://www.pearsoncreamery.com/public_html/...` that probably don't even exist; many hosts have `public_html` as the web root folder.
- On your line 200 and 233 you have `Templates/public_html/`
- On your line 235 you have `file:///C|/Users/...`
- Pay attention to your paths, when your HTML file goes to your hosting server all the paths will be based on the server folder structure.