# Adding "~" to the href for a html link

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following link inside my asp.net mvc razor view:-

```
<a class="brand" href="~/Home/Index/"> <img alt="test" src="~/Content/logo.png" /> </a>
```

But i am not sure what does the symbol ~ inside the src & href do ? as removing this symbol will still reference to the correct imag and the correct url ? can anyone advice please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116(v=vs.100).aspx

`~` means `root` directory of your application.

Following SO post may help to know more.

[slash(/) vs tilde slash (~/) in style sheet path in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424114/slash-vs-tilde-slash-in-style-sheet-path-in-asp-net)

In your case removing the `~` from path will make your path absolute. Then the url will become `http://example.com/absoulte/path`. If your project root directory and web root is same, it will make no difference. You may also want to visit these links.

http://www.boogiejack.com/server_paths.html

[Absolute path & Relative Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181805/absolute-path-relative-path)

Comment: Removing '~' will make your path absolute path after site host.

Comment: i think the difference is as follow, if i deploy my web application on IIS under let say www.example.com/myApp , then / will return www.example.com , while ~/ will return www.example.com/myApp. so i should use ~ since on production server i might deploy my application under www.ourcompany.com/CustomApp/myApp, so i need the link to refernece www.ourcompnay.com/CustomApp/myApp nad not just www.ourcompnay.com. what do u think is my point right ?

Comment: Your msdn link was very usefull, but currently i am assuming that any code inside asp.net mvc Razor view will be processed as a server side control, without explicitly writing this? that why ~ was recognized well ,, what do u think?

Comment: @johnG Yes it was processed as server side control.

Answer (score 1):

The `~` symbol represents the currently logged in users home directory on a linux/unix system.

Comment: but i am working on a windows server & IIS  and not on a unix server, so does this have any meaning on windows server ?

Comment: @johnG I am not certain - it doesnt work as intended on my windows machine but this answer may be of use to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077558/use-of-tilde-in-asp-net-path

Answer (score 1):

"~" is notation for webroot.. if you have IIS C:/inetpub/wwwroot/ is your webroot..

it has its existence (origin) from UNIX `~` which denotes home directory

Answer (score 0):

`~` is your 'home' folder, on Unix it is eg. /home/andy (it is taken from $HOME variable - and it can be set by you to any other folder)