# Relative or absolute path

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In `<a href="/tips/page.html">`

/tips/page.html is a relative path or absolute path?

**EDIT:**
This question is not duplicate. i have read `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181805/absolute-path-relative-path`. That question says it is absolute path while `http://www.coderanch.com/t/628765/Servlets/java/Relative-absolute-path` says it is relative. therefore i have asked.

Comment: See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)

Comment: it will be absolute from your current web application context URL.

Comment: it took more time to create a SO question than to query Google with "relative path".

Comment: Not sure why people vote this question to close as unclear. The question is pretty clear: is this path relative or absolute for the HTML page where the link (`<a>`) is placed?

Comment: i have googled it but some says it is relative and some says it is absolute

Answer (score 0):

That is an absolute path
An absolute path is one wherein you give complete path of the resource. Usually it starts with the root directory (/) 
A relative path is often the one where you don't give the complete path; it is usually the current location of the resource

Comment: in that case, / is referring to the current directory and we are not giving the complete path. It should be then relative path.

Comment: please read `http://www.coderanch.com/t/628765/Servlets/java/Relative-absolute-path`. In this it is saying that this is relative path.

Comment: @aLearner it will be way better if you do your tests about it, then come up with your conclusion.