# Nginx alias only working for index.html

Tags: nginx

I am trying to server to Angular2 apps at:
http://my_ip/arc-client
the index gets downloaded but then for the other files, the browser tries at :
http://my_ip/(*.js | *.css)

instead of :

http://my_ip/arc-client/(*.js | *.css)

I know I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure out what.
Here's my Nginx config :

```
server {
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    location /arc-client/dev/ {
            alias /home/MrMan/arc-client/www/;
            index index.html;
    }

    location /arc-overseer-client/ {
            alias /home/MrMan/arc-overseer-client/dist/;
            index index.html;
    }
```

Comment: You have specified your resource files (js & css) using a relative path. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181805/absolute-path-relative-path) for more.

Comment: Thank you, I changed the base tag to my server address but now Nginx returns 504 for other files...

Comment: Check the access log and error log .

Comment: It helped me understand some behaviors but there is nothing about it in the error or the access log. Even if I try http://my_ip/arc-client/somefile.js